# maven still doesn't work with variable setup

Tags: maven

Maven still doesn't work with these variable setup

**JAVA_HOME**

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
```

**M2_HOME**

```
M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9
```

**PATH**

```
PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;%M2_HOME\bin%
```

**M2**

```
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin
```

**Path**

```
Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%
```

After setting these variables I restarted command line but no effect. When I typed `mvn` or `mvn --version` I get output `'mvn' is not recognized as command...`

Any ideas?

Comment: Try %M2_HOME%\bin in your PATH.  2nd percent sign appears to be in the wrong spot.

Comment: I tried. I get output now: `Error: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory. M2_HOME = "C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9" Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of the Maven instalation`

Comment: I deliberately installed Maven to a directory that is not in /Program Files.  Sometimes that space causes problems.

Comment: First directory that i installed maven was C:\. Then after these errors i tried with program files directory.

Comment: I don't know, then.  Working for me.  You're doing something else wrong.  Create a brand new command shell; reboot your machine; something....

Comment: I tried with C:\ directory again same problem. What could I do wrong then. I have seen installation instructions and I go through them

Comment: I tried to reboot, same

Comment: Go into a command shell and type "set" to see all your environment variables.  I'm guessing that you're blind to a small typo that's undoing you.

Comment: I copied it out. I'm not seeing typo. Also i tried to rename M2 -> M3
`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73`

`M3=C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\apache-maven\src\bin`

`M3_HOME=C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\apache-maven\src`

`MAVEN_HOME=C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\apache-maven\src`

`MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m`

`Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\apache-maven\src\bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things which are needed to run Maven is:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
```

and:

```
PATH = %PATH;C:\...\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
```

Nothing more is needed. (Replace '...' with the real location of your installation).